# Button used to calculate crashes app

Tags: android

I'm attempting to make a simple food calorie calculator using radio buttons, when I click my "display calories" button it crashes the app, my understanding is that it should call the "display_calories" method which parses the integer from an edittext field and multiplies that by the integer generated through the radiobuttons then changes the textview to that value, but instead crashes my app, why does it do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, explanations more so!

Activity

public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

```
int sub_weight = 0;

EditText weight;
TextView calories;
Button display;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    weight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_weight);
    calories = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cal_total);
    display = (Button)findViewById(R.id.display);

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v){

    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.radiopork:
            if (checked)
                sub_weight = sub_weight + 2;
            break;
        case R.id.radiochicken:
            if (checked)
                sub_weight = sub_weight + 7;
            break;
        case R.id.radiobeef:
            if (checked)
                sub_weight = sub_weight + 9;
            break;
        case R.id.radiosalmon:
            if (checked)
                sub_weight = sub_weight + 13;
            break;
        case R.id.radiocod:
            if (checked)
                sub_weight = sub_weight + 17;
            break;
        case R.id.radiocereal:
            if (checked)
                sub_weight = sub_weight + 18;
            break;
        case R.id.radioporridge:
            if (checked)
                sub_weight = sub_weight + 23;
            break;
        case R.id.radiotoast:
            if (checked)
                sub_weight = sub_weight + 26;
            break;
        case R.id.radiocrisps:
            if (checked)
                sub_weight = sub_weight + 29;
            break;
        case R.id.radionoodle:
            if (checked)
                sub_weight = sub_weight + 33;
            break;


    }

    }
public void display_calories(View v){

    String m = weight.getText().toString();
    int x =  Integer.parseInt(m);
    int y = x * sub_weight;
    calories.setText(y);

}
```

}

activity xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity2">

<TextView android:text="@string/calorie_counter" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/weight"
    android:id="@+id/edit_weight"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pork"
    android:id="@+id/radiopork"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chicken"
    android:id="@+id/radiochicken"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiopork"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Beef"
    android:id="@+id/radiobeef"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiochicken"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Salmon"
    android:id="@+id/radiosalmon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiobeef"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cod"
    android:id="@+id/radiocod"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiosalmon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cereal"
    android:id="@+id/radiocereal"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radiopork"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Porridge"
    android:id="@+id/radioporridge"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radiochicken"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radiocereal"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radiocereal"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toast"
    android:id="@+id/radiotoast"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioporridge"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioporridge"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radioporridge"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Crisps"
    android:id="@+id/radiocrisps"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiotoast"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pot Noodle"
    android:id="@+id/radionoodle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radiocrisps"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radiocrisps"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radiocrisps"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Display Meal Calories"
    android:id="@+id/display"
    android:onClick="display_calories"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_weight"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radiochicken"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radiochicken"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Meal Calorie Total:"
    android:id="@+id/cal_total"
    android:layout_above="@+id/save"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp" />
```

Logcat

```
    03-03 21:37:42.117    1784-1784/com.example.michael.foodapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.michael.foodapp, PID: 1784
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource    ID #0x384
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4122)
        at com.example.michael.foodapp.MainActivity2.display_calories(MainActivity2.java:104)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
calories.setText(y);
```

should be:

```
calories.setText(y+"");
```

so that y is parsed as a string instead of an int. When passed an int, the view will look for a resource with the id of y instead of displaying that int.

Answer (score 2):

You tried to setText to an int.  So it was treated as a resource id, which didn't exist, so you crashed.  Convert the value to a string, then call setText on the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashes because y can't be set as text,you need to add ""+ before

So for text add this:

```
calories.setText(""+y);
```

And add proper width and height for Edit Text like this(otherwise user can't type anything,it's too small):

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    ...
```

And you need to add if statement to check if the Edit Field is empty like this(otherwise you'll get  a crash):

```
if (weight.getText().toString().matches(""))
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
       ...
    }
```

So the full code is

```
if (weight.getText().toString().matches(""))
    {
        calories.setText("You need to add text");
    }
    else
    {
        String m = weight.getText().toString();
        int x = Integer.parseInt(m);
        int y = x * sub_weight;
        calories.setText(""+y);
    }
```